# Enforce limit on mongodb bulk API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'd like to delete a large number of old documents from one collection and so it makes sense to use the bulk api. Deleting them is as simple as:

```js
var bulk = db.myCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulk.find({
  _id: {
    $lt: oldestAllowedId
  }
}).remove();

bulk.execute();
```

The only problem is this will attempt to delete every single document matching this criteria and in this case that is millions of documents, so for performance reasons I don't want to delete them all at once. I want to enforce a limit on the operation so that I can do something like `bulk.limit(10000).execute();` and space the operations out by a few seconds to prevent locking the database for longer than necessary. However I have been unable to find any options that can be passed to bulk for limiting the number it executes.

Is there a way to limit bulk operations in this manner?

Before anyone mentions it, I know that bulk will split operations into 1000 document chunks automatically, but it will still execute all of those operations sequentially as fast as it can. This results in a much larger performance impact than I can deal with right now.

Comment: Why don't you simply use [(in shell terms) `db.collection.remove({"_id":{$lt:oldestIdAllowed}})`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/#remove-all-documents-that-match-a-condition)?

Comment: Did you try `bulk.find({...}).limit(10000).remove();` like you would for a normal query/cursor?

Comment: Nvm. Just tried it and it doesn't work for bulk.

Comment: Markus, I can totally use `.remove()`, and thats how I am going to do it this time, but I wanted to know if its possible to enforce limits on bulk for better bulk operation performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate the array of `_id` that of those documents that match your query using the [`.forEach`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach) method. The best way to return that array is by using the [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct) method. You then use ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) operations to remove your documents.

```
var bulk = db.myCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

var ids = db.myCollection.distinct('_id', { '_id': { '$lt': oldestAllowedId } } );

ids.forEach(function(id) {
    bulk.find( { '_id': id } ).removeOne();
    count++;
    if (count % 1000 === 0) {
        // Execute per 1000 operations and re-init
        bulk.execute();
        // Here you can sleep for a while 
        bulk = db.myCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

// clean up queues
if (count > 0 ) {
    bulk.execute();
}
```

Comment: This is possible, but it's actually more efficient to use `var ids = db.collection.find(query, {_id:1})` and then `bulk.find({$in: ids}).remove()`, but I'm really just curious if I can do this all in one bulk operation.

Comment: @RobRiddle No! And  that is  because it is not possible to limit the number of documents using the `Bulk` API. Also you should use `distinct` to return and array of `_id` because `_id` is unique.

Comment: Find won't ever return duplicate results of `_id` since it's the default unique index for mongo, so none of the extra logic provided by mongo `distinct` is necessary for that query. If it were a different field it might be.